# HAML Syntax highlighting misalignment

Tags: html, css, haml, syntax-highlighting

Hoping this is a quick fix,

I have a some HAML I would like to have highlighted with the [prism](http://prismjs.com/) library.

```
%pre
  %code.language-haml
    &#37;header.post-header
    &#37;h1= data.title
    &#37;time{ datetime: data.date }= pretty_date(data.date)
```

only it's coming out like this

[image: miss-alignment]

how do I get it to look like this

[image: correct alignment]

it's pretty frustrating, if I leave it unescaped it will not be visible.

Comment: Do you indent with spaces or tabs ?

Comment: I am using HAML so it has to be all either spaces or tabs, The file is geared for spaces. if you indent two spaces it's considered nesting in haml.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually just hacked it using the `&nbsp;` HTML escape HTML code for spaces and then aligned them all using that.